# clockpicker timeformat exception in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to change the timeformat of clockpicker in jquery.

```
time data '019:14PM:00' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'
```

this error is occur.
and code is :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.clockpicker').clockpicker({
    timeFormat:  "hh:mm:ss"

    });
});
```

Comment: I think the "PM" chars are not expected in the specified format..., try passing something like: "19:14:00". P.S: When do you exactly get that error? On Init or on change event? And do you populate some default value for the picker?

Comment: Hi.. This is the default timeFormat of clockpicker. I can't pass manually.